# Clojure, Monger sort and return newest record

Tags: clojure, monger

I have a collection called `automongo` on my local replica set for testing purposes and I am using the Clojure `Monger` library to read and write to my replica set.

I have achieved what I wanted to in terms of writing to the database, however I am struggling to achieve what I want when attempting to read the data.

My collection contains:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55facc57349562661f575bbc"), "last_customer_id" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55facc793495626592cba8af"), "last_customer_id" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55facc8d3495626631deefe7"), "last_customer_id" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55facce4349562663c5563e6"), "last_customer_id" : NumberLong(89) }
```

and in the mongo shell I can do this:

```
db.automongo.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

which returns the correct data.

I have attempted the following in `Monger`

`(find db "automongo" {:sort -1 :limit 1})`

which returns a DBCursor as the result, but it doesn't seem to contain the expected data (from what I can tell, im expecting a json looking object)

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The monger syntax is possibly wrong. The map argument is used for searching/filtering the documents. Its syntax of sorting is different - http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/querying.html#monger_query_dsl